# Eclipse Workspace Corrupted due to improper shutdown

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with Eclipse juno on windows7-64bit OS. Due to sudden power problem my system got shutdown, when i restart the Eclipse next start, Eclipse fails to load the workspace. It freezes on startup, or the workspace does not show up. It seems the workspace gets corrupted every time Eclipse is not shut down properly.

One way to fix the startup is

rm -rf ~/workspace/.metadata

After doing this, of course, settings are gone, projects have to be reimported etc. - It's really a pain :( and I don't understand why it has to be this way. Other applications seem to be able to keep their data intact, even if they are killed.

Can you suggest ways to remedy this problem? Are there ways of recovering a corrupted workspace including the settings?

thanks in advance

Comment: Gets corrupted? Does it say that it `workspace cannot be created at the same location...` etc ? What does it say?

Comment: Have you tried removing .markers.snap files in: workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\(Project name) ? Sometimes these also cause your Eclipse to hang.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can edit your shortcut to eclipse and add behind the line -clean as runtime parameter. It should clean your workspace and it might fix your corruption.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

So your shortcut would be something like:

`"C:\Program Files(x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe" -clean`

EDIT: Make sure once you've used this to remove it again after, you don't want to clean your eclipse every time you start it.

Comment: This has helped me in the past. However, be careful not to leave this enabled as it slows down your Eclipse loading time. Just do it once to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

from Vissol.ca

- create a new workspace
- import new (android) project(s) from existing source(s)
- good to go...

then you can backup original workspace , delete it and recreate it if desired.